# sudo ./install.sh cant run the script [SOLVED]

Tags: linux, sudo

Using RPi 4 model B Rev 1.4, Raspberry Pi OS.

I'm trying to install [MCC's DAQ hats](https://github.com/mccdaq/daqhats).

I have the followed all the instructions but when I try to run,

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

I get the following,

`sudo: ./install.sh: command not found`

I have tried changing `install.sh` to be recognized as an executable with

`chmod +x install.sh`

but now get,

`sudo: unable to execute ./install.sh: No such file or directory`

Also tried,

`./install.sh`

but

`bash: ./install.sh: Permission denied`

What am I missing here?

Requested information,

```
$ pwd
$ /home/daqhats

$ df .
Filesystem    1K-blocks   Used       Available   Use%   Mounted on
/dev/root     27494780    115021792  15053292    43%    /

$ mount
A tonne of stuff, the Pi isn't on a network so cant cut & paste

$ ls -l install.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 1562 Feb 6 2023 install.sh
$ chmod a+x ./install.sh
$ ls -l install.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 1562 Feb 6 2023 install.sh
```

Fist lines of script,

```
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]: then
   echo "This script must be run as root, i. e. 'sudo ./install'" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
```

Solution: I was finally able to get the R Pi onto a network & directly clone the directory from `git` (as opposed to copying across using a USB stick) & it all worked like clock work.

Comment: Obvious first question to ask here: did you misspell install in the line `sudo ./insatll.sh` here only, or did you mistype it on the cmdline, too?

Comment: @DavidArno no just here, I'll edit it

Comment: OK, next thing to try is `chmod a+x ./install.sh`. Just `+x` only marks it executable for the user, not for root. `a+x` sets it for user, group and other.

Comment: Just tried it but get `sudo: unable to execute ./install.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: H,, I'm not being much use here it seems. One last suggestion from me then before I admit I've no idea and hope someone more clued up turns up :) What happens if you replace `./install.sh` with the full path to the script? `sudo \`pwd\`/install.sh` for example?

Comment: I get the `command not found` error again

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requested information to the question. Always *copy&paste* the command together with the resulting output and/or error message(s). Show the output of the commands `pwd`, `df .`, `mount`, `ls -l install.sh` and the first line of the script. (I'm searching for different possible errors here.)

Comment: @Bodo requested information added to OP

Comment: Hmm, that shows `-rw-r--r--` as the permissions on the script. Is that after `chmod a+x ./install.sh`?

Comment: OOps forgot I undid the `chmod` will edit as appropriate

Comment: The permissions `-rw-r--r--` are unexpected after `chmod +x`.How did you copy the MCC DAQ HAT Library? Use the same way to copy&paste the commands and output. BTW: `/home/daqhats` does not match the installation instructions.

Comment: @Bodo see comment above, have redone the `chmod`

Comment: How did you get the software on your Raspberry Pi? Do you have file systems like FAT32 or mounted with `noexec` option? That was the purpose of the request for the `mount` output.

Comment: I just transferred the files on a USB drive

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems likely that the issue is related to the 3rd party software; i.e.`daqhats`.

Comment: I must admit that all I can currently do is wild guessing about possible causes for the error messages. You don't make it easy to help because you don't provide all requested information. Re-typing commands and/or output might introduce or hide errors. The best way to provide the information would be to copy&paste the whole command sequence and the output to the question. If you don't have (and cannot create) a network or serial connection, paste the data into a text file and use the USB drive to get it to the system where you can paste it into the question. Show the output of `type sudo`.